# How to obtain the result of integrity_check PRAGMA using System.Data.SQLite component?

Tags: sqlite, c++-cli

I am converting a project that made calls directly to the unmanaged sqlite3.dll library to one using the managed wrapper SQLite.NET. One conversion that has stumped me is, how to obtain the result of the PRAGMA integrity_check command? According to the SQLite.NET help file for this command

> *If any problems are found, then a single string is returned which
>   is a description of all problems. If everything is in order, "ok" is
>   returned.*

The question is, how do I access that single string result?

The following is the C++/CLI code I am using to execute the command.

```
SQLiteConnection^ db = gcnew SQLiteConnection("DataSource=MyTest.db");
try
{
  db->Open();
  SQLiteCommand^ cmdIntegrity = gcnew SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA integrity_check;", db);
  cmdIntegrity->ExecuteNonQuery();
  db->Open();
} finally
{
  delete (IDisposable^) db;
}
```

Thanks for any assistance,
Phil Coveney

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are using the [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) thin library. I skimmed through the code for `SQLiteCommand` in [SQLite.cs](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs) and I found (like in ADO.net) a function called [`ExecuteScalar`](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L1773) that can be used in your case.

So, instead of using

```
cmdIntegrity->ExecuteNonQuery();
```

you should write something similar to (I have no experience in C++/CLI, but the meaning should be clear)

```
String ^result = cmdIntegrity->ExecuteScalar<String^>();
if(result->Equals("ok"))
{
  db->Open();
}
else
{
  //manage the error
}
```

I use a similar technique with [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org) library, in your case it shouldn't be too different.